# ng-options and ng-model preselected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I'm trying to preselect value with ng-options. Here's what

```
 <select ng-model="promocode.PRODUCT" ng-change="getSomething()" ng-options="product as product.NAME for product in products">
```

The problem is in selected by default value. I have `promocode.PRODUCT` object the same as in ng-options, but angular set default value empty.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Is `promocode.PRODUCT` literally the same object, or is it an object with the same values? What properties does `promocode.PRODUCT` have?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. 3 fields: {ID: "string", TYPE: "string", NAME: "string"}.

Comment: It it The _same_ object, or is just the _contents_ the same? Did you assign `products[x]` to `promocode.PRODUCT` somewhere?

Comment: Contents the same, yes. I thought that was enough.

Comment: Not really. The problem is that angular is comparing selected items with something like `==`. Objects don 't really play nice with that. (Try: `console.log({} == {})`). That's why you need a `track by` to tell angular to compare the `id` properties, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your products have some kind of `id` property, this should do the trick:

```
 <select ng-model="promocode.PRODUCT"
    ng-change="getSomething()"
    ng-options="product as product.NAME for product in products track by product.id">
```

`track by product.id` tells angular to compare array items by their `id` property, instead of comparing equality between objects.

Here's some more info on [tracking / ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-and-track-by-).

And a working example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.products = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'FirstProduct'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'SecondProduct'
  }];

  $scope.promocode = {
    product: { // Here I am using a placeholder product to illustrate that 
      id: 2    // the select is identifying the correct row by it's `id`.
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controller">
  <select ng-model="promocode.product" ng-change="getSomething()" ng-options="product as product.name for product in products track by product.id">
  </select>
  <br/>
  {{promocode.product}}
</div>
```

A better option would be to select the correct row, like this:

```
$scope.promocode = $scope.products[1];
```

Then you won't have to duplicate any data.

Comment: But assuming to docs, track by does't work with AS in ng-options... I had some throubles with this... can't mention what exactly...

Comment: @Buckwheat: I provided a working snippet. As you can see, there's no problem using `as` with `track by`.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming `product` has `id` property*, You need to use `select as label group by group for value in array track by trackexpr`, Read [DOCs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select)

```
 <select ng-model="promocode.PRODUCT"
    ng-change="getSomething()"
    ng-options="product as product.NAME for product in products track by product.ID">
 </select>
```

[image: jsFiddle]

Comment: Don't know about the downvoter, this seems correct. But I would do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zshdb051/1/ (assigning the product to the promocode)

Comment: You're changing the model binding from `product` to `product.NAME`. That's fundamentally changing how the select works. (So no, @devqon, this answer isn't correct)

Comment: Never mind, something went wrong with saving the jsfiddle :)

Comment: Dude, you are rescuer.) This works. By as I mention, AS doesn't works together with track by in ng-options. For the future readers.

Comment: @Buckwheat  You should select Cerbrus answer

Comment: @Satpal, Done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<select ng-model="promocode.PRODUCT"
    ng-change="getSomething()"
    ng-options="product as product.NAME for product in products track by product.ID">
    <option selected disabled>{{Your default value}}</option>
 </select>
```